# Bower install: No versions available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, bower, bower-install

I successfully registered my own library into bower:

```
bower register angular-ngkit https://github.com/daveoncode/angular-ngkit-bower.git
```

and I'm able to install it using:

```
bower install angular-ngkit
```

But by using simply:

```
bower install
```

or

```
bower info angular-ngkit
```

I get "**No versions available**" exception and I don't understand why, since using

```
git tag
```

I can see my latest (and only) release named "0.2"

I previously published the library under the name "angular-ngkit" using another git repo and then I unregistered it (using `curl -X DELETE repo_url`) and re-registered with the new repo url and I also executed the command:

```
bower cache clean
```

...so why bower is not working as it should?

**UPDATE:**

if I define the dependency to my library in **bower.json** as `"angular-ngkit": "*"` I'm able to run `bower install` properly... but it's not acceptable :(

Comment: bower info angular-ngkit returns the expected results. Is this question still relevant?

Comment: are you sure? it returns "No versions available." at the bottom in my case! :(

Comment: You are right, my mistake - missed it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that Bower does not see any versions of your package is that your repository contains only a single tag - [v1.0](https://github.com/daveoncode/angular-ngkit-bower/tree/v1.0) - which does not follow semantic versioning.
Bower versions can be Git tags or branches. The version number must be a valid [semantic version](http://semver.org/) (semver).
The reason that you manage to install using a star target ("angular-ngkit": "*") is that in this case if there are not valid tags, Bower will fallback to the latest commit on master.

Comment: Previously I named the tag 0.1 and the problem was the same... so what should I do?

Comment: a valid semver version should be in the format of MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH. I suggest looking at semver.org. You can use this nodejs module for validating your version number - https://github.com/npm/node-semver

Comment: ok, solved by adding patch version (1.0.0)... I was sure that it was optional, but it's mandatory :P Thank you!!